# Response URL is returning previous Imgur image URL instead of current image URL

Tags: c#, imgur, system.net

I've built a new Unity project that makes use of C# and System.Net to access Imgur's API. I'm able to pull images into my application from anywhere, and I can upload screenshots to Imgur through my new application's client ID. I'm able to get a decent amount of response data on a successful upload, but the URL in the response is always outdated by 1. **If I just uploaded Screenshot D, the URL I get back will link to Screenshot C, and so on.**

Here is what the response data looks like:

[image]

This is the result I've gotten across all attempts, which includes using `w.UploadValuesAsync()` and in trying both Anonymous and OAuth2 (no callback) versions of Imgur applications.

Here is the bulk of my code, which is sourced [from here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1151550/how-can-i-upload-a-screenshot-directly-to-imgur.html).

```
public void UploadThatScreenshot()
{
    StartCoroutine(AppScreenshotUpload());
}

IEnumerator AppScreenshotUpload()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(Application.persistentDataPath + filename);

    //Make sure that the file save properly
    float startTime = Time.time;
    while (false == File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + filename))
    {
        if (Time.time - startTime > 5.0f)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        yield return null;
    }

    //Read the saved file back into bytes
    byte[] rawImage = File.ReadAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + filename);

    //Before we try uploading it to Imgur we need a Server Certificate Validation Callback
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = MyRemoteCertificateValidationCallback;

    //Attempt to upload the image
    using (var w = new WebClient())
    {
        string clientID = "a95bb1ad4f8bcb8";
        w.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Client-ID " + clientID);
        var values = new NameValueCollection
         {
             { "image", Convert.ToBase64String(rawImage) },
             { "type", "base64" },
         };

        byte[] response = w.UploadValues("https://api.imgur.com/3/image.xml", values);
        string returnResponse = XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(response)).ToString();

        Debug.Log(returnResponse);
    }
}
```

Why is the URL I get back from `w.UploadValues(...)` always behind by one?